# Parsing an HTML like String in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

So I have a string like this

```
string = "<user>username 1<notes>Notes of User 1</notes></user> <user>username 2<notes>Notes of User 2</notes></user>"
```

How could I parse the string in Javascript or JQuery to pull out the "Notes" of either user 1 or user 2.

So I'll have a variable like this:

```
variable = user;

printout notes of user.
```

Comment: FWIW, that looks a whole heck of a lot like XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to identify the notes of user1 or user2 you need to change your xml a bit

```
string = "<user>username 1<notes id='user1'>Notes of User 1</notes></user> <user>username 2<notes>Notes of User 2</notes></user>"
```

notice that i added `id=user1`

```
alert($(string).find("notes[id='user1']").text());
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qa5sP/

---

**EDIT** after the -1 :(

> No, jQuery selectors do not parse XML. 
>   This may appear to work at times, but it's invalid and browser-dependent.

So, here is the `parseXML` way:

```
 xmlDoc = $.parseXML(string),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    $title = $xml.find("notes[id='user1']").text();

alert($title);
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Qa5sP/1/)

Comment: No, jQuery selectors do not parse XML. This may appear to work at times, but it's invalid and browser-dependent.

Comment: hows `id='user1'` relevant here?

Comment: That seems like an easy way to do it, I'm wondering if there's a way to do it without adding an extra id tag to each of the notes, or possibly via class names, the reason why is because each note could be associated with multiple users.  e.g. A note could be associated with users 1, 2, and 3

Answer (score 4):

You mean an XML like string, not a HTML like string. jQuery has a lovely XML parser for that http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: I enjoy the thumbs down, but note that standard HTML parsers *can* parse the string listed above.  The issue hasn't been fully sussed out to say this is the only correct answer.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. However I think it's obvious that this is XML and therefore an appropriate parser should be used. The latest HTML5 spec doesn't specify tags of user or notes. I also wouldn't encourage the concept of HTML instead of XML, when modeling data.

Comment: @ghayes: "standard HTML parsers _can_ parse the string listed above". Actually, any ability to parse that string is **explicitly** and inherently _non_ -standard.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yByB8/4/).  It's simple to do using jQuery if you are using HTML-parsible XML (as seen above).

```
 string = "<user>username 1<notes>Notes of User 1</notes></user> <user>username 2<notes>Notes of User 2</notes></user>";
 var node = $("<div>" + string + "</div>");

 alert(node.find('notes').text());
 node.attachTo(document.body); //append to dom?
```

Comment: that is going to fetch notes of both the users

Comment: jQuery `$()` does not parse XML. This may appear to work at times, but it's not valid.

Comment: Are we sure this is XML?  Your presumption is nice, but not entirely consistent with the facts given.

Comment: +1 ghayes @Tomalak Geret'kal: i think you are a little unfair. here ghayes is trying to make the string a part of html of a non existent div and as $ will parse DOM, he could then parse it. also curious to see how this could be solved using `$.parseXML`

Comment: @naveen: I'm not being "unfair" at all. As I said, jQuery `$()` parses HTML, not XML. Last I checked, `<user>` and `<notes>` are not valid HTML tags.

Comment: According to jQuery documentation:  `XML data returned from an Ajax call can be passed to the $() function so individual elements of the XML structure can be retrieved using .find() and other DOM traversal methods.`  This would tend to say there is some level of support for parsing elements as above that are valid in the DOM given certain DOCTYPES.  What level of HTML/XHTML/XML compliance has the OP specified?

-- Example from jQuery docs: `$.post('url.xml', function(data) {
  var $child = $(data).find('child');
})`

Comment: @ghayes: That is under the section talking about `$(selector, [content])`. But the first parameter to `$()` in this answer is not a selector, but content. What we're doing here is `$(html, [ownerDocument])`, in the _next_ section, which says: `html - A string of HTML to create on the fly. Note that this parses HTML, not XML.`

Comment: @tomalak-geretkal - I concede that jQuery claims to parse HTML, but it does complex parsing by an 'innerHTML' tag-- based on this [compatability](http://caniuse.com/#search=xhtml), this should parse XHTML (which would fit the above) for every browser except lte IE8.  Thus, for compatibility and standard, you are strictly correct.

Comment: Yeah this is a custom formatted string, it's not an XML file persay but it's a string stored in a database.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go with this approach.

```
var xml = "<user>username 1<notes>Notes of User 1</notes></user> <user>username 2<notes>Notes of User 2</notes></user>";

function FindNotesByUserName(uName) {
    var node = $('<div/>').html(xml);
    return node.find(":contains('" + uName + "')").closest("user").find("notes").text();
}

var desiredNotes = FindNotesByUserName("username 2");
```

N.B: This is a minor alteration of what ghayes did. Just to meet OP requirement.